# Javascript returning SUM 0

Tags: javascript

Sorry for this basic JS question.

I have this code:

```
    const value0 = parseInt(this.value0); // 8500
    const value1 = parseInt(this.value1); // 3.5
    const value2 = parseInt(this.value2); // 5700
    const value3 = parseInt(this.value3); // 0.3
    const valueExtra = parseInt(this.valueExtra); // 10.5

let myResult = 0

        if (value0 > (value1 * value2)) {
          myResult = (value1 * value2) * value3;
        } else {
          myResult = valueExtra * value3;
        }
        return ( myResult )
```

my value is always 0.

I know it's because let is not changing, but I don't know why.

Could you help me, please?

Comment: Include `value0`, `value1` and `value2` in your question. And where are you definining them? are they within this function? include the whole function so we can help you

Comment: with multiple if any value of ( value1, value2, value3 ) = zero, the result will equal zero too.

Comment: if one of `value0/1/2` or `valueExtra` is 0 the result will be 0

Comment: Is that all of your code? Are `value0`, `value1`, `value2`, `value3`, `valueExtra` defined in your code?

Comment: Values are defined and I can see it if I do a console.log

Comment: You didn't defined the value of valueExtra, the execution will go with else condition.

Comment: sorry @Mina just forgot to add it here

Comment: `parseInt` returns **Integers** (hence the name parse**Int**), never `0.3`. You get `0` at that point. *Whatever* multplied by `0` is `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parseInt('0.3')` is 0. So one of your values is 0, so the result will always be 0. Try using `parseFloat` instead.

```js
const value0 = parseInt(`8500`);
const value1 = parseInt(`3.5`);
const value2 = parseInt(`5700`);
const value3 = parseInt(`0.3`);
const valueExtra = 1;

console.log(`values check: ${[value0, value1, value2, value3]}`);

let myResult = 0;

if (value0 > (value1 * value2)) {
  myResult = (value1 * value2) * value3;
  console.log(`parseInt: value0 > (value1 * value2)=> ${myResult}`);
} else {
  myResult = valueExtra * value3;
  console.log(`parseInt: else => ${myResult}`);
}

// use parseFloat
const [v0, v1, v2, v3, vE] = [
  parseFloat(`8500`),
  parseFloat(`3.5`),
  parseFloat(`5700`),
  parseFloat(`0.3`),
  1 ];

console.log(`values check: ${[v0, v1, v2, v3]}`);

if (v0 > (v1 * v2)) {
  myResult = (v1 * v2) * v3;
  console.log(`parseFloat: v0 > (v1 * v2)=> ${myResult}`);
} else {
  myResult = vE * v3;
  console.log(`parseFloat: else => ${myResult}`);
}
```

Comment: That work!! Replace parseInt with ParseFloat